# Printing dynamically created WindowsFormsHost in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, printing

I'm trying to print a WindowsFormsHost in a WPF application.
It prints ok, if the WindowsFormsHost object is created by xaml, but it prints an empty page if I create WindowsFormsHost in code.

**How do I have to create WindowsFormsHost object in code in order to get it to printout?**

Here is the simplified but working code:

```
            PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.TextBox ctrl = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                ctrl.Text = "Test";
                ctrl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
#if RUNTIME
                WindowsFormsHost wfh = new WindowsFormsHost();
                wfh.Child = ctrl;
                FrameworkElement visual = wfh;
#else
                WFHostTest.Child = ctrl;
                FrameworkElement visual = WFHostTest;
#endif

                visual.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
                visual.Measure(new Size(dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, dialog.PrintableAreaHeight));   
                visual.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, dialog.PrintableAreaHeight)); 
                visual.UpdateLayout();
                dialog.PrintVisual(visual, "Test");
            }
```

This code prints the TextBox only when RUNTIME is not defined.
If RUNTIME is defined it prints an empty page.
WFHostTest is defined in xaml as

```
<WindowsFormsHost Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="WFHostTest" />
```

Comment: More information:
I can add the dynamically created wfh to a visible grid on screen, then wfh prints.
But this way I cannot set width and height, it's allways in the same size as on the screen.

Comment: Do you only have problems with WindowsFormsHost or printing in general ? Have you looked at http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/02/230940.html which has a complete example ?

Comment: I only have problems with WindowsFormsHost, everything else prints correct. Petzold doesn't print WindowsFormsHost.